# Ocultar diretório de domínio utilizando htaccess ou router no cakephp

Tags: cakephp, htaccess, cakephp-2, mod-rewrite

estou com dificuldades em criar uma configuração no .htaccess para ocultar uma pasta do meu site.

Meu domínio tem a seguinte estrutura: www.site.com.br/cake , onde estão os arquivos e pastas referentes ao projeto. Quero ocultar o diretório /cake, mostrando apenas o domínio em todas as páginas, www.site.com.br/

O arquivo .htaccess atual possui a seguinte configuração:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Já tentei:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cake/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com.br/$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cake/index.php [L]
```

E não funciona, dá erro 500. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: É melhor mover a pasta cake para um nível acima da pasta publica, /home/cakephp/, ou seja sem acesso direto, já que você pode mover para onde quiser a pasta webroot, e até mesmo renomeá-la, apos isso, só definir o caminho na constante define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))); que se encontra na index.php desta pasta publica, apontando para o /home/cakephp/

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 2):

O que você quer não é necessariamente ocultar o diretório, mas sim direcionar o acesso a partir da pasta raiz para a partir da pasta cake.

Crie na pasta raiz o arquivo .htaccess e adicione o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(?!cake/)(.*)$ cake/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Se o erro 500 está acontecendo é provável que você não tenha habilitado o modrewrite, para isto abra o arquivo httpd.conf e procure a linha que contenha algo como:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

É provavel que ela esteja comentada:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Remova o hash (#) salve o arquivo e reinicie o Apache.

Comment: Opa, removi o # do LoadModule porém continua o erro 500

Comment: Olá @Kevin.F, chegou a reiniciar o Apache? Tem algo a mais no teu htaccess?

Comment: Sim tem alguns outros rewrite, e ja reinicia o apache.

Comment: @Kevin.F formula uma pergunta e posta o mod_rewrite todo por favor, em seguida me manda o link

Comment: segue minha pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203591/ocultar-diret%C3%B3rio-de-dominio-utilizando-htaccess