# deixar / no final da url

Tags: php, htaccess

Gostaria de esconder a extensão .php do *site* de todas as páginas e ficar com barra no final exemplo: `www.meusite.com.br/pagina/`

Também gostaria de ocultar as páginas que estão como *landing pages*, que estão assim: `www.meusite.com.br/lp/br/rj/exemplo.php`

Teria que ficar assim: `www.meusite.com.br/exempo/` (obs: iria ocultar `lp/br/rj/` )

Alguém pode ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Isto é mais do que deixar o `/` no final e remover o `.php`. Você pode tentar algo semelhante a isto [Ocultar diretório de domínio utilizando htaccess ou router no cakephp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72674/3635)

Acredito que o seu `.htaccess` ficaria assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(?!lp/br/rj/)(.*)/$ lp/br/rj/$1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Se quiser o endereço `http://exemplo.com/contato` e `http://exemplo.com/contato/` acessem o mesmo arquivo php, use assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(?!lp/br/rj/)(.*)(/|)$ lp/br/rj/$1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, quando clico na página "contato" da erro, será que deveria já colocar na header <a href="contato/"> dessa forma?

Comment: Mas existe o arquivo na pasta chamado `/lp/br/rj/contato.php`? Porque este foi o entendimento do seu pedido @user27508

Comment: @user27508 acho que entendi o que você precisa, eu editei a resposta, me avisa por favor se faltar algo

Comment: detalhe,para  funcionar  a reescrita da url você precisa certificar que esta habilitado o mod_rewrite no seu apache.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues o link que postei no corpo da resposta tem a orientação ativar o mod_rewrite :)