# Como mudar link da minha página com htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess

Minha url normal é:

```
http://localhost/paginas/noticias.php?id=1
```

Eu queria assim:

```
http://localhost/paginas/noticias/1
```

O id 1 é gerado pelo php, não sei como faço para que fique desse jeito no htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie o arquivo htaccess dentro da pasta `./paginas` e escreva o seguinte conteúdo:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^noticias/([0-9]+)$ noticias.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Se tiver páginas além do noticias.php, então use assim:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Neste caso você pode acessar páginas que serão equivalentes:

- `http://exemplo/paginas/noticias/8` => `http://exemplo/paginas/noticias.php?id=8`
- `http://exemplo/paginas/blog/2` => `http://exemplo/paginas/blog.php?id=2`
- `http://exemplo/paginas/produto/4` => `http://exemplo/paginas/produto.php?id=4`
- `http://exemplo/paginas/artigo/5` => `http://exemplo/paginas/artigo.php?id=5`

Note que para isto você deve ativar o mod_rewrite como é explicado neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72674/3635)

Comment: Não deu certo, deu Not Found

Comment: @Dinho era erro no htaccess, troque `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` por `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, veja que editei a resposta com o código corrigido.

Comment: Deu certo, mas quando abro a página dá erro no php dizendo que: Notice: Undefined variable: id.

Comment: Será se isso é por causa do htaccess?

Comment: @Dinho Não eu testei aqui um php assim: `<?php

echo $_GET['id'];` e funcionou, o erro tá no teu php, não tem nada haver com o .htaccess. Como está o teu php?

Comment: <?php $noticiass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 10cms_noticias WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<?php $i = 0; while($edit = mysql_fetch_assoc($noticiass)){ $i++; ?>
<?php echo $edit['titulo']; ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: @Dinho Se você abrir o url direto assim também vai dar erro `http://exemplo/paginas/noticias.php?id=8` o erro está no seu código, você setou a variável depois de executar a query, veja que no primeiro select você já solicita o $id, mas você só setou ele depois, o certo **é** `<?php $id = $_GET['id']; $noticiass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 10cms_noticias WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error()); ?> <?php $i = 0; while($edit = mysql_fetch_assoc($noticiass)){ $i++; ?> <?php echo $edit['titulo']; ?> <?php } ?>`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26174/discussion-between-dinho-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: @Dinho Conseguiu?

Comment: Deu certo com seu código, puxou tudo, mas eu puxei uma include do meu topo, e ela ficou sem estilo.

Comment: @Dinho Isto é acontece por causa da `BASE`, a cada diretorio do path o nivel de acesso ao CSS e JS muda o bom é criar as pastas na raiz. Isto já é outro problema, por favor crie uma pergunta com detalhes sobre como usa o CSS e JS e fale sobre o problema com htaccess, amanhã eu respondo, boa noite -- O Problemas de mudar o link já tá resolvido.

Comment: Boa noite. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Dinho notei que tem várias respostas em suas perguntas, mas você não aceitou nenhum como correta. Para aceitar uma resposta como correta clique no desenho ✓ que fica ao lado da resposta que mais lhe ajudou. Para entender como funciona o StackOverflow veja este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Nem sabia disso, foi mal kkk

Comment: @Dinho tem outras perguntas, além da minha. Tranquilo, até amanhã.