# Ocultar diretório de dominio utilizando htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Preciso ocultar o diretório da `url`.

**Como fica:**

```
www.meusite.com.br/Site/view/telaInicial.php
```

**Como preciso:**

```
www.meusite.com.br/telaInicial.php
```

Meu `.htaccess` atualmente:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

> Atualmente meu .htaccess só faz essa função acima que não tem nada ver com a pergunta, porém não sei se atrapalha as demais abaixo

O que já tentei no meu `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(?!cake/)(.*)$ cake/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Porém me ocorre o error 500.

Já tirei o hash (#) da frente do `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` no httpd.conf do apache, e ja reinicieo o apache e nada.

Sei que possui uma pergunta idêntica [Ocultar diretório de domínio utilizando htaccess ou router no cakephp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72642/ocultar-diret%C3%B3rio-de-dom%C3%ADnio-utilizando-htaccess-ou-router-no-cakephp/72674?noredirect=1#comment416848_72674) porém a resposta da mesma não serviu para mim.

Imagem da estrutura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Kevin eu fiz uma resposta, mas ainda não dá para ter certeza, poderia informar a estrutura de pastas, tipo se cake é o root ou se htdocs é o root e como esta a estrutura deste projeto especifico?

Comment: o root é a pasta Site após vem as demais dentro view etc... tenho um index na pasta root que redireciona para `view/telaInicial.php`

Comment: E a pasta cake, fica aonde exatamente? Poderia mandar um print pra ficar mais fácil de entender?

Comment: Não tem cake, a minha estrutura é diferente. É como expliquei ai na pergunta.

Comment: Então porque no Regex usou `cake/$1`? Poderia postar a estrutura das pasta por favor? Pode ser até uma imagem.

Comment: Ok, segue na pergunta a imagem da estrutura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este .htaccess parece muito errado:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(?!cake/)(.*)$ cake/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Primeiro não é necessário 2 `RewriteEngine on`, segundo o uso de RewriteBase é mais complicado, se o .htaccess não estiver na root então você deverá especificar o caminho todo no `RewriteBase`, fora que você usou `mod_rewrite` mas deixou regras do lado de fora, vou lhe pedir que faça **duas tentativas**:

1. Remova o `IfModule` e `RewriteBase` ajuste para isto:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(?!cake/)(.*)$ cake/$1 [QSA,L] # Redireciona para dentro da pasta cake

   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] # qualquer path que não tiver . no nome tenta acessar algo com .php
   ```

   Se não der certo ajuste para isto, pois talvez esteja tudo dentro da pasta `cake`:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(?!cake/)(.*)$ cake/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ cake/$1.php [NC,L]
   ```
2. Se ocorrer o erro 500, a segunda tentativa é adicionar o ifmodule para ter certeza do modulo estar ativo:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(?!cake/)(.*)$ cake/$1 [QSA,L] 
       RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ cake/$1.php [NC,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Ainda sim o erro pode ser causado por redirecionamentos contínuos, mas para ter certeza apenas se informar a estrutura das pastas.